# Query Consequtive Events Occuring on Item on Oracle Databse

Tags: sql, oracle, match-recognize

I have an Oracle table (Oracle database v12.2.0.2.1) that records when an item has a protection (PROT) placed on it and it's subsequent protection removal (RMPR).

The rule is, an item should not be protected twice consecutively. In other words, before a second protection can be placed on an item, the previous one needs to be removed first.

The users of the database don't always follow this rule and inadvertently place a protection on an item before they removed the previous one. I want to audit the table and query for consecutive 'PROT' on the same item. Here is a sample of my data where:

- ITEM_ID is the unique identifier of the item
- EVENT_ID is the unique identifier of the PROT or RMPR event
- EVENT_TYPE is the type of event (PROT or RMPR)

| TENURE_NUMBER_ID | EVENT_NUMBER | EVENT_TYPE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1099391 | 5994168 | RMPR |
| 1099391 | 5994169 | PROT |
| 1099489 | 5963896 | PROT |
| 1099489 | 5994168 | RMPR |
| 1099489 | 5994169 | PROT |
| 1099491 | 5963896 | PROT |
| 1099491 | 5994168 | RMPR |
| 1099491 | 5994169 | PROT |
| 1099491 | 5990993 | PROT |
| 1099491 | 5983849 | RMPR |
| 1099967 | 5989988 | PROT |
| 1099967 | 5989990 | PROT |
| 1099967 | 5989992 | RMPR |
| 1099967 | 5989993 | PROT |
| 1099967 | 5989999 | PROT |

Comment: In other words if the number of PROT vs RMPR per item are bigger than 1 and are different would do the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sql
with t(TENURE_NUMBER_ID, EVENT_NUMBER, EVENT_TYPE) as (
  select 1099391, 5994168, 'RMPR' from dual union all
  select 1099391, 5994169, 'PROT' from dual union all
  select 1099489, 5963896, 'PROT' from dual union all
  select 1099489, 5994168, 'RMPR' from dual union all
  select 1099489, 5994169, 'PROT' from dual union all
  select 1099491, 5963896, 'PROT' from dual union all
  select 1099491, 5994168, 'RMPR' from dual union all
  select 1099491, 5994169, 'PROT' from dual union all
  select 1099491, 5990993, 'PROT' from dual union all
  select 1099491, 5983849, 'RMPR' from dual union all
  select 1099967, 5989988, 'PROT' from dual union all
  select 1099967, 5989990, 'PROT' from dual union all
  select 1099967, 5989992, 'RMPR' from dual union all
  select 1099967, 5989993, 'PROT' from dual union all
  select 1099967, 5989999, 'PROT' from dual
)
select *
from t
  match_recognize (
     partition by TENURE_NUMBER_ID
     order by EVENT_NUMBER
     measures 
        count(same.*) as cnt
       ,CLASSIFIER() AS pttrn
     all rows per match
     pattern( (same|diff)*)
     define
       same as prev(EVENT_TYPE) = EVENT_TYPE
      ,diff as lnnvl(prev(EVENT_TYPE) = EVENT_TYPE)
  )
```

DBFiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/f4MqsPWX

Answer (score 3):

You can also use

```
last_value(EVENT_TYPE) over(PARTITION BY TENURE_NUMBER_ID ORDER BY EVENT_NUMBER
            ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS last_event_type
```

The rows

```
where last_event_type = event_type
```

are the duplicates, so filtering also on `last_event_type = 'PROT'` will give the answer .